# Update shown data after a POST request

Tags: flutter

I have a `ListView` inside of a `FutureBuilder` in my main widget.
All entries in this list are requested from a web backend with a `GET` request.

There is a second widget with a dialog to add new data to the backend.
I use a `POST` request to send the data.
After the data is sent the app returns to the main widget.

Both my requests are bundled in a class `HttpHandler` (as `Future<List<Data>> getData()` and `Future<List<Data>> postData(Data data)`).
I have only one instance of this `HttpHandler` in a file `globals.dart`.
Both widgets use this global handler.

I want to update the `ListView` in my main widget after a sent data to the backend.
How can I do this?

A refresh button (using `setState(...)`) is already in use and working.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use "setState", You can make a new class "HttpHandler" that extends a ChangeNotifier using the Provider architecture.

In your widget define in the Widget tree a ChangeNotifierProvider using the "HttpHandler" change notifier.

In "getData" calls in "HttpHandler" call NotifyListeners() at the end to refresh Widget GUI under the ChangeNotifierProvider.

Comment: I don't mind using `setState()` but I don't know how to call it from my dialog widget.